# Nativescript ListPicker breaks strings into individual characters

Tags: android, ios, angular, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm trying to use Nativescript's ListPicker to collect data in my ios/android application. I'm running into a problem where instead of showing each individual string or number, it breaks everything down into individual characters.

For example, I want to give a user an option between Left or Right, but instead of having two options for left and right, the `list picker` shows each character. [Click here for the image of this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCodw.png)

I have the same problem when trying to show a list of numbers using the `list picker`, as it breaks numbers up into individual characters and adds the commas from the array in-between. I'm trying to allow a user to select a height here. [Click here for the image of this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GWSz.png)

I'm using `native script-angular`.

Here's the code:

Html file:

```
<ListPicker items="{{ sides }}" ></ListPicker>
 <StackLayout orientation="horizontal">
            <ListPicker items="{{ feet }}" ></ListPicker>
            <ListPicker items="{{ inches }}" ></ListPicker>
 </StackLayout>
```

TypeScript File:

```
sides = ["Left", "Right"];
feet = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
inches = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11];
```

I've never used the ListPicker before so I could be using it incorrectly but based on my research, this execution should work fine. If anyone has a fix I'd appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer - in the Html file, instead of formatting the  tag as I did, use this format:

`<ListPicker [items]="sides" ></ListPicker>`

The square brackets on items and no curly brackets on what you want to put in the listpicker apparently are all the difference